# How to add an extra larger chapter title on another page?

Tags: titles, chapters

I'm writing my thesis.

If I just use this code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside, spanish]{book}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=3.4cm, top=4.7cm, bottom=4.1cm ]{geometry}
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage[toc, title]{appendix} % titletoc
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}
\renewcommand{\restoreapp}{} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{allplain}  
\usepackage{titleps}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
    \ifbool{allplain}{\sethead{}{}{\thepage}{}}{}%
}%
\newpagestyle{ruledplain}{%
    \headrule
    \sethead[My Name][][\thepage]
    {CAPÍTULO \thechapter: \, \chaptertitle}{}{\thepage}}%
\usepackage{emptypage}
\pagestyle{plain}
\overfullrule=5pt

\begin{document}
\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
   Some text
\setbool{allplain}{true}
\pagestyle{ruledplain}
\chapter{INTRODUCCIÓN}
  some long text
\end{document}
```

Every time I start a new chapter I'm getting

[image]

But I would like to have a page with just a large title, then a blank page and then the title again with the long text, i.e the chapter title would be repeated.
Something like this:

[image]

[image]

How can I get it?

I can get a blank page by just writing \pagebreak after \chapter. But it only writes the title one.  If I repeat the process it would create another different chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully the thesis from the original question is finished by now - but for future visitors this answer may still be useful.

Using the `titlesec` package the appearance of chapter titles can be modified. The package defines the macro `\titleformat` with seven arguments, specifying the format (font size etc.), layout and contents of the title block. The text of the title is inserted between the sixth argument (the *before-code*) and the optional seventh argument (the *after-code*). In the before-code you can set the title to be just the number and the title text, without the word *Chapter*. In the after-code you can specify a blank page and a repetition of the chapter title. See the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) of `titlesec` for more information on the arguments of `\titleformat`.

Some remarks:

The example code also used starred chapters, which should presumably have a different format. This can be achieved by defining `\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}`.

The example code used the package `titleps`. In order to use `titleps` together with `titlesec` you need to load `titlesec` with the `pagestyles` option (`\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}`) and remove `\usepackage{titleps}`.

To use Spanish for fixed phrases (figure captions etc.) I have added `\usepackage{babel}` which inherits the class option `spanish`.

To take a screenshot of multiple pages I reduced the page height in the MWE.

The title formatting includes a `\MakeUppercase` command which makes the title upper case (unsurprisingly).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside, spanish]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=3.4cm, top=4.7cm, bottom=4.1cm, paperheight=12cm ]{geometry}
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage[toc, title]{appendix} % titletoc
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}
\renewcommand{\restoreapp}{} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{allplain}  
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
    \ifbool{allplain}{\sethead{}{}{\thepage}{}}{}%
}%
\newpagestyle{ruledplain}{%
    \headrule
    \sethead[My Name][][\thepage]
    {CAPÍTULO \thechapter: \, \chaptertitle}{}{\thepage}}%
\usepackage{emptypage}
\pagestyle{plain}
\overfullrule=5pt
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\bfseries\Huge\raggedleft}
    {}
    {0ex}
    {\Roman{chapter} --\MakeUppercase}
    [\clearpage\null\clearpage\normalsize\centering\Roman{chapter}.\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}]

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
    {\bfseries\Huge}
    {}
    {0ex}
    {\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}
%\show\chapter
\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
%   Some text
\setbool{allplain}{true}
\pagestyle{ruledplain}
\chapter{Introducción}
  some long text
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]